# Java - Recursive function of the Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: java

I can't seem to convert the following algorithm into Java successfully, please forgive the horrible picture quality but a question I'm working on asks:

[image: Euclidean Algorithm]

I have tried to use the following code to represent the Euclidean Algorithm, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't really know how I would go about representing it in Java code. Any help?

```
public static int gcd(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return x;
    } else if (x >= y && y > 0) {
        return gcd(y, (x % y));
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're following the text-book algorithm correctly. It's just that the text-book algorithm is incomplete - as it doesn't consider the case where neither category is satisfied.

Comment: How does it not work?  What actually happens when you call it?  What arguments do you pass, and what does it return?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm sure that OP's immediate problem is that the code does not compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ah, quite right.  The OP still should have mentioned that, rather than "but it doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no arbitrary order between x and y.

Comment: `return y == 0 ? x : gcd(y,x%y);` is all you need. doesn't matter which is greater. It will however take 1 recursion more though.

Comment: FYI: This answer was previously more helpful (see edit history).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not complete!

What if `x < y`? Your code does not return a value then!

What the book fails to mention is that the two parameters to the function do not necessarily need to be in descending order (ie `x >= y`). What you need to do is compute the `gcd` considering this fact.

Simply you can do the following:

```
public static int gcd ( int x , int y )
{
    if ( y == 0 )                        
        return x;
    else if ( x >= y && y > 0)
        return gcd ( y , x % y );
    else return gcd ( y , x );        // if x < y then go ahead and switch them around.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You need to consider what happens when `y > x`, and return the result from the final `else` branch (hint: `x` and `y` can freely switch places).

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

Your code does not compile, because there is no *catch all* clause that return from the function.

It really depends on whether you are going to pass negative values of `y` into this function.  If you expect only positive values, just throw an exception.

```
public static int gcd(int x, int y) {

    if (y == 0) {

        return x;

    } else if (x >= y && y > 0) {

        return gcd(y, (x % y));

    }

    throw
        new IllegalArgumentException(
            String.format(
                "Unexpected values for x(%d) and y(%d)",
                Integer.valueOf( x ),
                Integer.valueOf( y )
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to include negative values.

Comment: @m92 The recurrence formula from the assignment does not cover negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have that accounts for negative numbers:

```
public static int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return x;
    if (x < 0)
        return gcd(x * -1, y); //turns the first parameter to a positive if it's initally negative
    if (y < 0)
        return gcd(x, y * -1); //turns the second parameter to a positive if it's initally negative
    if (y <= x && x % y == 0)
        return y;

    return gcd(y, x%y);
}
```

Note with negative numbers, if you try to find the greatest common divisor, and either of the numbers is negative, you can just change it to a positive and the result would be the same.

If both of the numbers are negative, then I'm not sure what the gcd should be. 1? -1? idk so I left that out. The code I have just treats it as if they were both positive.